# MSBuild - Using older version of assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have:

- A library of shared functionality [A]
- Another library [B] which
  references v1 of A [A1]

My current Visual Studio solution has:

- A dll [L], which (file) references B
- A WindowsService [S], which (project) references L and also has a file reference to an updated, but backwards compatible, version of A, [A2].

When I build the solution in Visual Studio everything works fine.  The bin folder for S contains L, B and A2 (which is compatible with B so works great).

However if I build using MSBuild (through TeamBuild), the final build folder ends up with L, B and A1.  A1 doesn't have the new features of library A required by S, so S falls over when you try to run it.

---

I have read a few things suggesting it's to do with the build ordering of the .sln being ignored by MSBuild.

I have spotted that the bin directory for L contains B and A1, as I'd expect, because nothing in there has any reference to A2.  So presumably when MSBuild has built L (locally pulling in B and A1) and S (pulling in L and A2) it then has to merge all the binaries into the final output for the build.  What I don't understand is what makes it choose A1 (from the L bin) over A2 (from the S bin)?

I appreciate there's nothing to say it should be the other way round either, but I just have no idea what the criteria MSBuild uses to make this call.

Can anybody shed any light on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Tom the way msbuild in teambuild works is that all the output dlls of all the projects are placed in the outputdirectory. This output directory is shared for all the projects in your solution. So if you have different versions of the same dll they will overwrite each other.

The way around this is to either use subdirectories for such projects $(Outdir)\SpecificDir or rename the dlls with a version tag ie A.1.0.dll and A.dll